# "knock against someone" to mean not "your fault"

Tags: meaning

I'm struggling to find examples of something I swear I've heard being said before, and I just want to make sure I'm using the saying correctly and in the right context.

Say you're working on a project that involves using a specific software, which the boss knows is buggy or limiting. The boss talks to you about the end result and isn't happy, but he says this:

"It's not **a knock against you**, I'm sure you did the best under these circumstances."

Is that a correct way to use it? And if not, what should you say instead? Maybe I just misheard the saying if I'm using it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would understand what you meant, though I've never heard the expression. I have heard the expression "It's not a black mark against you" which takes the same form.

Personally, I'd suggest using *"It's not a criticism of you"* as a plainer expression of the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct, but I wanted to supply some references.

[**knock against**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/knock+against) from McGraw hill:

> to bump against someone or something. Mickey knocked against Mary and said he was sorry. I didn't mean to knock against your sore knee.

Both of the examples are quite literal there.

**knock** from [Collins via TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/knock)

> verb
>
> 6. (tr) informal to criticize adversely; belittle: to knock someone's work.
>
> noun
>
> 16. informal unfavourable criticism

So, from those definitions, we can replace the words "knock against" in your sentence with "unfavourable criticism":

"It's not an **unfavourable criticism of** you, I'm sure you did the best under these circumstances."

It sounds kind of clunky when put that way, but it demonstrates that you are using the phrase correctly.

Comment: Your verb reference from McGraw Hill isn't much use, but your noun reference from Collins is.